# linq to entity using two tables

Tags: vb.net, linq

EDITED:  I am retrieving some order data and am trying to grab the product description from another table using the productID from the first table. The code below works fine but I need to query the products table using the productid to get the string,product description

```
 Dim result = From c In ctx.orders
                         Where c.CustomerId = 13
                Select New With
                {c.OrderDate,
                 c.PurchaseOrderNumber,
                 c.ProductId,
                 c.ProductPrice,
                 c.ProductQty}
```

I tried the suggestions below and get a "field or property named productid doesnt exist" error
using this method

```
 Dim result = From c In ctx.orders
                         Where c.CustomerId = 13
                  Join prod In ctx.products on c.ProductId Equals prod.Id
                Select New With
                {c.OrderDate,
                 c.PurchaseOrderNumber,
                 prod.Description,
                 c.ProductPrice,
                 c.ProductQty}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the [join operator C# version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) and [join operator VB version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx)

```
Dim result = From c In ctx.orders
             Join prod In ctx.products On c.ProductId Equals prod.Id
             Where c.CustomerId = custid
             Select New With
                    {c.OrderDate,
                      prod.Description
                     c.ProductPrice,
                     c.ProductQty}
```

I made a sample class to test the join and this worked perfectly. Are you sure it loaded the products tables and it has the property?

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim ctx As List(Of X) = New List(Of X)
    Dim x1 As X = New X()
    x1.One = 1
    x1.Two = 2
    Dim x2 As X = New X()
    x2.One = 10
    x2.Two = 20
    ctx.Add(x1)
    ctx.Add(x2)

    Dim ctx2 As List(Of Y) = New List(Of Y)
    Dim y1 As Y = New Y()
    y1.Three = 1
    y1.Four = 2
    Dim y2 As Y = New Y()
    y2.Three = 10
    y2.Four = 20
    ctx2.Add(y1)
    ctx2.Add(y2)

    Dim result = From c In ctx
         Join prod In ctx2 On c.One Equals prod.Three
         Where c.One = 1
         Select New With
                {c.One,
                 prod.Four,
                 c.Two}

    For Each a In result
        Console.Beep()
    Next

    Console.Read()
End Sub

Class X
    Public Property One As Integer
    Public Property Two As Integer
End Class

Class Y
    Public Property Three As Integer
    Public Property Four As Integer
End Class

End Module
```

Comment: VS didnt like the "into prodDesc" part. I changed the query somewhat removinf the "into prodDesc" and changing the prodDesc.Description to prod.Description and it errs saying (" no field productId exists), which obviously isn't true

Comment: @dinotom Try the updated code. Sorry, I was doing some C# stuff and it appears there are some slight differences.

Comment: That is similar to what I was doing from your original suggestion, I am still getting the same error "Field or property named productId not found on selected data but it does populate the first column of the grid ( it seems to barf on the prod.description)

Comment: Now are the products loaded, I only ask because when I see ctx normally that a context is sometimes lazy loaded

Comment: @dinotom I posted an example join using some throwaway classes to illustrate the join. CAn you verify the ctx.products collection has data and that data contains a Product Id?

Comment: well one problem that's obvious after sleeping was that c.customerid equals prod.id will always be an error because that should have been c.ProductId Equals prod.Id BUT having changed that I still get the error that the field productid was not found on the selected data source, which cant be true because the first result from my question produces a table with all the product id's

Comment: Brad, the error was in the datafield in the column it was looking for productid instead of description thank you for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this : 
    Dim result = From c In ctx.orders
                         .Where(c => c.CustomerId = 13)
                         .SelectMany(c => c.products);
Then you will get all the products in oders.